# What happens when my attribute score is level 9 and I have the Extraordinary Focus feat?

Tags: feats, open-legend

In *Open Legend*, *Extraordinary Focus* is a feat that

> heightens your power and for the purposes of determining
>   your attribute dice for action rolls, you treat the chosen attribute
>   as if it was one greater

Having an attribute score of 9 is the maximum you can attain, so how can it be upgraded by one?

What happens when your attribute score is already 9? does it go to from 3d10 to 4d6, following the pattern? Or does it do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### An Attribute Score of 10 has attribute dice 4d8

The table that can be found in [Chapter 1 - Character Creation](https://openlegendrpg.com/core-rules/01-character-creation#record-attribute-dice) under "Record Attribute Dice" includes a line for an Attribute Score of 10 as the last line, listing 4d8 as the corresponding attribute dice.